# Weighted smooth histogram

Tags: histograms

I have a large list $L$ ($|L| \sim 100000$) of pairs $\{x_i,w_i\} \in \mathbf{R} \times [0,1]$ subject to the constraint that

$\qquad \sum w_i = 1.$

I would like to use $L$ to graph a smooth function which "approximates" the PDF

$\qquad \sum w_i \cdot \delta(x - x_i)$

If all the $w_i$ were equal to $1/|L|$, then I could simply take the list of the numbers $x_i$ and apply SmoothHistogram. Is there any  way to do a "weighted" smooth histogram? If not, some other way?

In practice, the numbers $w_i$ satisfy $5/|L| \ge w_i \ge 1/(5 |L|)$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = Transpose[{RandomReal[10, 100], Normalize @ RandomReal[1, 100]}];
```

Try [`WeightedData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedData.html):

```
wd = WeightedData @@ Transpose[data]

SmoothHistogram[wd]
```

[image]

Compare with `SmoothHistogram` of data without the weights:

```
SmoothHistogram[data[[All,1]]]
```

[image]

Comment: This completely and succinctly answers my question, and includes a working example that makes it easy for me to reproduce. Thanks!

Comment: @user67131, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept. And welcome to mma.se.